# XCode Compatibility Issue with different versions

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently made a project using XCode 4.5.1 on iOS 10.8.

I want to run this project on a different computer using XCode 4.4.1 on iOS 10.7.5.

It is currently giving me the error:

XCode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Is there a way to open the project on the other computer without having to redo all the delegations and such?

I have tried turning off AutoLayout and running it on the iOS 10.7.5 computer and it is still giving the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the deployment target to the ios version you want to run the project on.

[image]